# TCP socket, reconnection and "Connection reset" error

Tags: kotlin, sockets, error-handling, tcp, client

I'm creating a TCP socket connection between a Python server and an Android client (in Kotlin).
The data exchange works pretty well, and right now I'm trying to handle the reconnection of the client to the server in case of server disconnection.

This is my Client class

```
class Client(var context: Context): AutoCloseable {
    private var client: Socket? = null
    private var sender: Sender? = null
    private var receiver: Receiver? = null
    var reconnected = true
    val dataReceivedListeners = mutableListOf<(ByteArray) -> Unit>()

    fun sendData(data: ByteArray) {
        sender?.sendData(data)
    }


    override fun close() {
        client?.close()
    }

  

    init {


        client = Socket()
        val address = InetSocketAddress("192.168.0.***", 8888)
        

        client!!.connect(address, 3000)
      
        val outputStream = client?.getOutputStream()  // Reads the output stream of the socket        
        val inputStream = client?.getInputStream()  // Reads the input stream of the socket

        sender = Sender(DataOutputStream(outputStream))
        receiver = Receiver(DataInputStream(inputStream))

        receiver?.dataReceivedListeners?.add { data ->
            dataReceivedListeners.forEach { listener ->
                listener(data)
            }
        }        
        receiver?.start()  // The receiver Thread is started
       }


    // Sender class: writes the data on the output stream and flushes it
    private inner class Sender(private val dataOutputStream: DataOutputStream) {
        fun sendData(data: ByteArray) {
            dataOutputStream.write(data)
            dataOutputStream.flush()
        }
        fun close() {
            dataOutputStream.close()
        }
    }

    // Receiver class. A Thread is created to send and receive data simultaneously
    private inner class Receiver(private val dataInputStream: DataInputStream) : Thread() {
        val dataReceivedListeners = mutableListOf<(ByteArray) -> Unit>()
        private var running = true


        // Run method, executed in Loop as the Thread starts
        override fun run() {
            val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
            var bytesRead: Int
            val dataBuilder = StringBuilder()

            // The data are read in chunks of 1024 bits
            while (running) {
                try {
                   
                    bytesRead = dataInputStream.read(buffer)
                    if (bytesRead <= 0) {
                        break
                    }
                    val data = buffer.copyOf(bytesRead)                    
                    dataBuilder.append(String(data))   // dataBuilder collect the received message               
                    if (dataBuilder.contains("\n")) {
                        val completeData = dataBuilder.toString().toByteArray()
                        dataReceivedListeners.forEach { listener ->
                            listener(completeData)
                        }                        
                        dataBuilder.setLength(0) // Clear the StringBuilder for the next set of data
                    }
                } catch (e: SocketException) {
                    reconnected = false
                    var tries = 0
                    while (tries < 5) {
                        if (!reconnected) {
                            reconnect()
                            tries += 1
                            Thread.sleep(1000)
                        } else {
                            break
                        }
                    }
                    if (tries >= 5 && !reconnected) {
                        Log.d("Reconnection failed", "All reconnection attempts failed")
                        break
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        fun close() {
            dataInputStream.close()
        }
    }


    private fun reconnect() {
        sender?.close()
        receiver?.close()
        client?.close()
        client = null
        sender = null
        receiver = null
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000)            
            client = Socket()  // Create a new socket and connect to the server
            val address = InetSocketAddress("192.168.0.***", 8888)
            client!!.connect(address, 2000)
            
            val outputStream = client?.getOutputStream()  // Update the sender and receiver with new streams
            val inputStream = client?.getInputStream()
            sender = Sender(DataOutputStream(outputStream))
            receiver = Receiver(DataInputStream(inputStream))

            receiver?.dataReceivedListeners?.add { data ->
                dataReceivedListeners.forEach { listener ->
                    listener(data)
                }
            }
            receiver?.start()

            reconnected = true
            Log.d("Reconnection", "Reconnection happened")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            reconnected = false
            Log.d("Reconnection failed", "Reconnection has failed")
        }
    }
}
```

When I voluntarily close the server endpoint in Python, I receive a "Connection reset" SocketException on line `bytesRead = dataInputStream.read(buffer)`. In this way the disconnection is detected and the reconnection process starts.

If now I reactivate the server in Python, the reconnection happens, but when the Kotlin code executes the `bytesRead = dataInputStream.read(buffer)` newly the "Connection reset" error is thrown.

I'm trying to solve this problem from days, but I've not found any working solution.
Any clue?

The Client class is used in the MainActivity class as part of a coroutine:

```
val myCoroutineScope = lifecycleScope
        var updates = 0

        if (myCoroutineJob == null || myCoroutineJob?.isCompleted == true) {
            myCoroutineScope.launch {
                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    client = Client(this@MainActivity)
                }

                // A listener function is created, it is used to handle the data as needed
                client?.dataReceivedListeners?.add { data ->
                    receivedText = String(data)

                    try {
                        updates += 1 
                        # ...
```

Comment: Usual mistakes here. You are assuming that every read fills the buffer. There is nothing that says so.